# SQL to RGui | Character Encoding Issue

Tags: sql-server, r, character-encoding, turkish

After running a query and saving the results to a .txt file, when I open that txt file by double clicking on it, everything is OK, there is no issue with Turkish characters. Like this:

> TRİKO

After making the R read the txt with read.csv, then I encounter this:

> TRÄ°KO

I use SQL Server 2014 Express and I think my collation isn't the problem.

The thing is when I copy the content in that txt file and paste it to a new txt file  that I created, R reads it just fine. I again see the capital i with the dot on top.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the encoding you are using in the text file? Have you told R what coding to expect via the `fileEncoding=` or `encoding=` parameters of read.csv?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken R has four options for encoding: Latin-1, UTF-8, unknown, bytes. I need UTF-8 for my case (I think) and when I set encoding="UTF-8" unfortunately, nothing changes.

Comment: What OS are you on? You need to know how the file *is* encoded, not how you want it encoded. And did you try `fileEncoding=`?

Comment: Windows 7. I use the following command on RGui to read the table: `x <- read.csv("file.txt", HEADER=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")` I haven't tried `fileEncoding=` though. I'll try it ASAP. By the way, thank you Mr. Flick.

Comment: If you're on Windows it seems unlikely the encoding would necessarily be UTF-8; the default tends to be "latin1". But the encoding of the file depends on how you wrote the file. The file only has one "true" encoding. The `iconvlist()` function should list all possible encoding that R can import.

Comment: > "then I encounter this: TRÄ°KO" - How do you encounter it? Are you opening the csv file in Excel?

Comment: Opening it with Excel is fine, opening it with Notepad is OK but when I try to see the rows in RGui, then I get the character encoding problem. Interestingly, if I copy the content in the csv to another csv that I created with simply right-clicking and choosing New -> Text Document and paste, then I don't see any character encoding problem while viewing the rows in RGui.

Comment: I am not familiar with R or RGui, but based on your description, the problem is exhibited for characters generated specifically by R and not by RGui, as RGui is able to display the characters fine if generated by non-R applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it worked but I added `fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"` and it worked.